# Tailwind custom pseudo element

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a single js file for a component that is used with several styles in my project.
On one page I have several buttons for some features, with a default background color set in the html file (for exemple `bg-gray-500`).
For buttons where the feature is activated I change the background color, currently with js, but therefore the bg color for the "activated feature" (for exemple bg-blue-500) is defined in the js and this is what I would like to move to the html file.
So, instead of having `<button type="button" class="bg-gray-500"></button>` and having the js removing the class `bg-gray-500` and adding the class `bg-blue-500`, I wonder if this is possible to have something like `<button type="button" class="bg-gray-500 selected:bg-blue-500"></button>` where the js would only have to add or remove the class `selected` to switch between the one and the other color, instead specifing the color itself.
Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may write simple plugin for custom [variants](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#adding-variants)

```js
// tailwing.config.js

const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    plugin(function({ addVariant }) {
      addVariant('selected', '&.selected');
      addVariant('parent-selected', '.selected &');
    })
  ],
}
```

HTML

```html
<div>
  <button class="bg-blue-500 selected:bg-red-500 selected">
    Button
  </button>
</div>

<div class="selected">
  <button class="bg-blue-500 parent-selected:bg-yellow-500">
    Button
  </button>
</div>
```

The magic here is `addVariant()` function where the first parameter is variant name (could be any but must be unique among all variants - in HTML use it like `selected:`), second - CSS selector (so `&.selected` means element with class `.selected`) or callback function which should return string as CSS selector

In a demo I created two cases just for example - toggle class on element itself or parent element

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/8Y3jD8gh4s) - toggle `selected` class to see effect